# PHP and IDE : annotation for array

Tags: php, autocomplete, annotations, ide

```
/**
Annotation ?????
*/ 

public function getProduct($id=null,$params=null) {

if (!empty($params['sku'])  {  
$sql.= " AND sku=:sku " ;
$sql_tab['sku']=$params['sku']; }
if (!empty($params['ean'])  {  
$sql.= " AND ean=:ean " ;
$sql_tab['ean']=$params['ean']; }

 // ..... 
}
```

Is there a way for my IDE (VS Code / IntelliJ) to help it about autocompletion, based on this quick example ?

I mean, what annotations should I have to for an array ($params here)?

Comment: Does the PHP version you are using support type hinting on variables themselves?

Comment: There's multiple ways to annotate arrays. Some [examples](https://scrutinizer-ci.com/docs/tools/php/php-analyzer/guides/annotating_code#type-reference) can be found here. You could add something like `@param string[] $params` for an array containing a list of strings.

Comment: I dont know what you are talking. 7.4

Comment: in 7.4 yuo can use something as `public function getProduct(int $id=null, array $params=null)  : bool {`

Comment: @splash58 "array" has been available as a type hint since something like 5.0; "int" has been available since 7.0, and frankly nobody should be using a version older than that any more. However, I _suspect_ the OP is asking for something more specific, although the question's not particularly clear.

Comment: @IMSoP I can be wrong, but, seems, ide's understand annotation in php code. But I have a practice only with phpstorm although )

Comment: @splash58 Yes, but marking something as an "array" is quite broad. I suspect the OP is hoping for some way of saying "array which must have a key 'sku' with a value which is an int". That said, the best fix is to change the code to expect an object of a particular class, and define the property types on the class.

Comment: I am asking, with this code (and no one other), to help the ide autocomplete. Not even "integer". Just while I type $class->getProduct(null,.... array( give me hints))

Comment: So, you want it to auto-complete the keys, like 'sku', 'ean', etc?